# Div over another div with overflow

Tags: html, css, overflow

I want to display some kind of tooltip on the left side of the long div(vertical).
And if I set the parend div css to overflow-y:auto; then the child div is not displayed. Here is a fiddle of the problem https://jsfiddle.net/wrwvc6Lc/2/
try to remove the overflow-y:auto; prop and everything is fine. 
Is there a way to do so, as I need the overflow prop.

```css
#infoBox {
  z-index: 1200;
  width:160px;
  height:90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
     
   background-color:white;
    overflow-y:auto; /* REMOVE THIS */
    border:1px solid red
    }
```

```html
<div id="infoBox">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text.
<div style="position:absolute; border:1px solid green; left:-90px; height:50px;width:100px;background-color:red">
Tooltip
</div>
</div>
```

**UPD:** I want that tooltip to be relative to the content inside the main infoBox div (3-4 text block with tooltip), so placing that tooltip out of the infobox is not ok.

[image]

Comment: If you remove that tooltip from `#infoBox` and place it as a sibling element, wrapped in a new containing element, you will be able to circumvent this issue. See: https://jsfiddle.net/wrwvc6Lc/3/ (adjust tooltip positioning as required)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError thanks, but I want that tooltip to be ralative to content inside the main infoBox div, as I will have about 3-4 such tooltips in that one infoBox div

Comment: You have to remove the div outside the inner div to make use of `overflow`

Comment: Have you tried switching those elements around then? https://jsfiddle.net/wrwvc6Lc/9/ - they will be relative so long as you don't define a `top` property (I mean, as *relative* as an *absolutely* positioned element can get - it is taken out of the normal document flow after all)

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError This will miss the scrollbars on the wrapper div. This is just an example to show you what is missing on wrapper div at the moment. https://jsfiddle.net/wrwvc6Lc/11/

Comment: Sorry, @LarsMertens not sure what you mean there. Could you demonstrate this or elaborate further?

Comment: Following comments from @UncaughtTypeError and you, does this solve the issue? https://jsfiddle.net/6pw936ss/ It's similar to the solution proposed. I'm just confused why this is not the solution. If you want to repeat the infoBox and tooltip, the infoBox needs to be a class, and then you can try repeating them and see if it does what you want? Sorry some mix/matching of the CSS may be needed  between the parentdiv and infoBox for the scrollbars, but the point is I think a parent div is necessary suggested above.

Comment: Taking a look at that image you've recently included, and considering the `overflow` requirement, you'll need javascript for this to move the tooltip outside of the containing element (whenever it needs to appear) and position it based on its sibling element's position in the DOM, you will retrieve the sibling element's position (top & left) beforehand and store them in variables, which you will then use as your positioning values with an additional offset to space apart far enough.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError, well.. will try to do it with js. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The thing you're trying to do here is not possible (correct me if I'm wrong). Because `overflow: auto;` is required to set the scrollbars. But overflow also has an other property that every element inside the div with `overflow: auto;` can't go outside this element and will be cut off from this element which is intended.

Your concept can only work if you're not working with the `overflow: auto;` and you can't use scrollbars for this reason unfortunately.